# How to expand y axis scale

Tags: r, max, yaxis

```
library(ade4)
library(factoextra)
library(magrittr)
library(textshape)
library(describedata)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

bw.phen <- "BWphenology"

#select the columns you want to find correlations between

##columns must be numeric



bwphenselect <- bw.phen


bwphenselect <- BWphenology %>%
  select(`fingerprinted cultivar`, bud_break_jul, first_pistil_jul, last_pistil_jul, first_pollen_jul, last_pollen_jul, percent_overlap, flower_type, harvest_date_jul, harvest_date_d.a.d., season_length)



#find correlations

cor(na.omit(bwphenselect))

as.numeric <- 'fingerprinted cultivar'

scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 250, by = 50))

hist(bwphenselect$bud_break_jul, xlab = "Bud break julian date", scale_y_continuous(breaks = 6), breaks = 6, main = "Histogram of Bud Break Julian Date") 

hist(bwphenselect$first_pistil_jul, xlab = "First pistil julian date", breaks = 6, main = "Histogram of First Pistil Julian Date") +
  xlim = c(1000, 7000)

hist(bwphenselect$last_pistil_jul, xlab = "Last pistil julian date", breaks = 5, main = "Histogram of Last Pistil Julian Date") +
  xlim=c(100, 6000)

hist(bwphenselect$first_pollen_jul, xlab = "First pollen julian date", breaks = 6, main = "Histogram of First Pollen Julian Date") +
  xlim=c(1000, 6000)

hist(bwphenselect$last_pollen_jul, xlab = "Last pistil julian date", breaks = 5, main = "Histogram of Last Pistil Julian Date") + 


hist(bwphenselect$percent_overlap, xlab = "% overlap", breaks = 6, main = "Histogram of % Overlap")
```

Here is my code. I am having trouble getting the histograms to display the full scale of the y axis. Basically, the tops of the bars are overshooting the y scale.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: That doesn't help me at all. I don't understand what that means even after clicking the link.